# Is audio card necessary for audio input from USB webcam?

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have a WebCam for video calling. It is now hooked to my Pi and I can take pictures from it, but I just could not make the microphone work.

Many post here mentioned some USB audio card. Is it a must have? Can we do with USB powered microphone and speak without the audio card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, most USB webcams have a built in audio card. The USB audio cards you see people referring to are one's like these:

[image]

These are for if you want 3.5mm jack audio input. If you had a microphone with a 3.5mm jack. They also have a 3.5mm output.